# Terminal shortcut for deleting keys on a redis instance

Tags: redis

I have a development redis instance and I'm trying to create a terminal shortcut to quickly delete: All Keys in DB 10 starting with the word FORUM.

I've tried to create this alias in my bash_profile:

`redis-cli -h [XXX] -p [XXX] -a [XXX] SELECT 10 KEYS "forum:*" | xargs redis-cli -h [XXX] -p [XXX] -a [XXX] SELECT 10 DEL`

but that doesn't work (err msg: wrong nbr of arguments for SELECT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a single command to the CLI so chaining the SELECT with KEYS/DEL results in an error.

Instead, use the `-n` switch to have redis-cli select database 10.